# How to parse a file with multiple JSON objects exported from masscan?

Tags: python, json

I tried to parse the file using the python standard library, but an json.decoder.JSONDecodeError occurred.

```
[
{   "ip": "221.233.195.68",   "timestamp": "1586336065", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "107.178.154.147",   "timestamp": "1586336065", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "109.90.3.6",   "timestamp": "1586336065", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "172.120.79.226",   "timestamp": "1586336091", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "180.25.188.35",   "timestamp": "1586336186", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "117.255.229.196",   "timestamp": "1586336186", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "50.87.6.164",   "timestamp": "1586336187", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "58.64.154.169",   "timestamp": "1586336187", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "200.5.50.217",   "timestamp": "1586336193", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
]
```

Comment: What error occurred? Please be specific and share the code that you used to parse the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `,` in the last element in the list
you can manually remove it so that it becomes a valid json
The valid Json for the given data would be:

```
[
{   "ip": "221.233.195.68",   "timestamp": "1586336065", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "107.178.154.147",   "timestamp": "1586336065", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "109.90.3.6",   "timestamp": "1586336065", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "172.120.79.226",   "timestamp": "1586336091", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "180.25.188.35",   "timestamp": "1586336186", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "117.255.229.196",   "timestamp": "1586336186", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "50.87.6.164",   "timestamp": "1586336187", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "58.64.154.169",   "timestamp": "1586336187", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] },
{   "ip": "200.5.50.217",   "timestamp": "1586336193", "ports": [ {"port": 8080, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 128} ] }
]
```